# ssh through proxy via dynamic port forwarding

Tags: ssh, proxy

I am trying to use dynamic port forwarding to ssh to various servers in my university from home.

I used local port forwarding successfully:

```
ssh -L 10001:server1:22 my_user@proxy_server
ssh -p 127.0.0.1:10001
```

but I am using 12 servers, and I'd like to create only one tunnel (dynamic).

Is it possible to configure ssh to use a SOCKS proxy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the '-L' option several times to have more then one forwarding through one ssh connection.
Like

```
ssh -L 10001:server_1:22 -L10002:server_2:22  -L ... my_user@proxy_server
```